# How to convert a bean to JSON using JSON-LIB

Tags: java, json, json-lib

Cn anyone show a example of generating a JSOn from a bean class using JSON-LIB?
   I am not able to find a example to understand this.

Thanks

Comment: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
MyBean mb = new MyBean();
JSON json = JSONObject.fromObject(mb);
```

Comment: If the bean has arrays ,list ,map defined how will this work?

Comment: I am getting the following error after trying this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException  ,i have simple employee bean class used json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar ,let me know what is wrong